# iOS: Can I use Texture Atlas already created with Adobe Animate?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, adobe, sprite-sheet

I know that I can add sequences of individual images in Xcode, and let it create the Texture Atlas. This process is well-described in easily-searched venues. (Like this one.)

I am getting atlases from designers, created with Adobe Animate (v18.0) already combined into the full sheet, and moreover with the accompanying XML file describing the animation. (In which sub-images and display frames do not match 1:1, so it's hard to see how Xcode would figure that out.)

It's not clear to me from the SpriteKit docs whether/how to use these pre-defined Texture Atlases. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting pre-baked texture atlases, with externally-generated descriptions of where the sprites should get their textures, you'll probably have to create your sprites using SKTextures that you create using the init(rect:in:) initializer of a SKTexture.

You'll need to read the sprite's extents out of the XML file, and then create a texture out of the atlas.  Then you can create a new SKTexture object that represents a part of the larger texture to act as your sprite's texture.

This is untested pseudocode, but it shows the process:

```
let spriteRect = (get the rect from the XML)
let atlas = SKTexture( imageNamed: "myTextureAtlas" )
let spriteTexture = SKTexture( rect:spriteRect, in:atlas )
let sprite = SKSpriteNode( texture:spriteTexture )
```

Once you have this process in place, you can animate the sprites using the usual methods, like setting up SKActions with a list of textures out of the texture atlas.

Comment: Thank you cc. I've more than half a mind to ask the artists to just give me all separate files and let Xcode create the atlas. But.. I think information (about specific animations would get lost. Looks like I have some experimenting to do.

Comment: One thing that isn't clear to me. It *seems* to me that the Xcode process involves just providing a collection of individual frames, and the build process creates the Texture Atlas and the descriptive XML file. In this case, how would Xcode know where the image boundaries are? Especially if the images are not uniformly dispersed?

Comment: If you let Xcode build the atlas, then it's all handled internally by the SpriteKit engine.  When you ask for SKSpriteNode( imageNamed:"(whatever)" ), it will just give you that named sprite as part of a texture atlas, just as if you had done the code above for a manually-handled atlas.  If your artists are giving you proprietary animation data, you're probably going to have to roll your own solution; the SpriteKit engine won't know what to do with an arbitrary XML file.  You'll need to parse it and translate that into SpriteKit directives.